# Blade @inject() not working on Laravel 5.2 for a custom Helper class

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I've created a custom Helper class under the App\Http\Helpers directory and I am injecting the class using the Blade `@inject()` injection like the following:

`@inject('Hello', 'App\Http\Helpers\Helper')`

And, I'm referencing `Hello` in the same view like the following:

`Hello::activity(1, 2, 3)`

However, this returns the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Hello' not found (View: /Users/sumon/Desktop/TimeCop/resources/views/diary/view.blade.php)`

Is there anything I'm missing?

Here's the full class Helper class I've created:

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Helpers;


class Helper
{
    public static function activity($keyboard, $clicks, $drags)
    {
        if (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 100) {

            return 100;
        } elseif (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 90) {

            return 90;
        } elseif (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 80) {

            return 80;
        } elseif (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 70) {

            return 70;
        } elseif (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 60) {

            return 60;
        } elseif (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 50) {

            return 50;
        } elseif (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 40) {

            return 40;
        } elseif (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 30) {

            return 30;
        } elseif (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 20) {

            return 20;
        } elseif (($keyboard + $clicks + $drags) / 3 >= 10) {

            return 10;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#service-injection) the `inject()` directive creates a variable to be used in the view context, not a reference to a class.
Try this:

```
{{ $Hello->activity(1, 2, 3) }}
```

PS: Also be sure to run `composer dump` after creating the `Helper` class

Comment: aah Man, I missed that. However, I don't need to dump the composer as the class is loading fine.